# Finding the eigenvalues of a matrix with particular symmetry

Tags: symmetry, linear-algebra

I have a matrix for which I want to get some analytical equations of the eigenvalues. 
The matrix is given as 
\begin{align}
 \mathbf A &= \begin{pmatrix}
  \epsilon_a & 0 & 0\\
  0 & \epsilon_b & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \epsilon_c
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \mathbf B &= 
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \\
   \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\
   \Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \\
  \end{pmatrix}\\
  \mathbf M &= 
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbf A &\mathbf  B \\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & -\mathbf A
  \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
   \epsilon_a & 0 & 0 & \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \\
   0 & \epsilon_b & 0 & \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\
   0 & 0 & \epsilon_c & \Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \\
   \Sigma_{11}^*& \Sigma_{21}^*& \Sigma_{31}^* & -\epsilon_a & 0 & 0\\
   \Sigma_{12}^*& \Sigma_{22}^*& \Sigma_{32}^* & 0 & -\epsilon_b & 0\\
   \Sigma_{13}^*& \Sigma_{23}^*& \Sigma_{33}^* & 0 & 0 & -\epsilon_c\\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
The diagonal elements of the matrix are real elements, other elements are complex.
By looking at the dimension one can guess that one need to solve a polynomial
of order 6 to get the eigenvalues. So it seems impossible to get an
exact answer for the eigenvalues. But there are some symmetries followed by
the matrix $\mathbf M$,
\begin{align}
 \mathcal C^{-1} \mathbf M \mathcal C &= -\mathbf M \\
 \mathcal C &= K \sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{I}_3
\end{align}
$K$ is the complex conjugation operator. I'm guessing This symmetry might give some constraints (like particle hole symmetry) which might lead to eigen values like
$$
\{w_1,w_2,w_3,-w_1,-w_2,-w_3\}
$$
I have computed the characteristic equation of the matrix but am unable to solve it. I'm not sure how to impose this anti-unitary kind of symmetry.

**Is there any way I can get the Eigenvalues for this matrix?**

Comment: You can apply the symmetry transformation to the eigenvalue equation, to show the relation between the eigenvalues of the eigenvectors related by the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I summarize below the results of the processing of an answer, results that I could prove if the space for an answer allows it. In the end I'll give a numerical example to clarify some important details.

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{A. Hermiticity and real eigenvalues}}$

From the very beginning the $\,6\times6\,$ matrix


<sup>\begin{align}
\mathbf M & \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0 & \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   0 & \epsilon_2 & 0 & \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   0 & 0 & \epsilon_3 & \Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \Sigma_{11}^*& \Sigma_{21}^*& \Sigma_{31}^* & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_1 & 0 & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \Sigma_{12}^*& \Sigma_{22}^*& \Sigma_{32}^* & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_2 & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \Sigma_{13}^*& \Sigma_{23}^*& \Sigma_{33}^* & 0 & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf A \hphantom{^{\dagger}} &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} \mathbf B \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-01a}\label{A-01a}\\   
   &\text{where}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf A & \boldsymbol{=}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} \epsilon_1  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_2 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_3 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
 \end{bmatrix}\:  \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3 \in \mathbb{R}  \quad \text{and} \quad 
  \mathbf B  \boldsymbol{=} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}\:  \Sigma_{ij} \in \mathbb{C} 
\tag{A-01b}\label{A-01b} 
\end{align}</sup>
 
is hermitian $\,\left(\mathbf M^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{=}\mathbf M\right)$, so it has real eigenvalues $\,\lambda_k \in  \mathbb{R}\left(k=1,\cdots,6\right)$. Moreover we have zero sum of these eigenvalues 
\begin{equation} 
  \sum\limits_{k\boldsymbol{=}1}^{k\boldsymbol{=}6}\lambda_k\boldsymbol{=}\rm{Trace}\left(\mathbf M\right)\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{A-02}\label{A-02} 
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{B. Property imposed on the matrix $\,\mathbf B$}}$

The $\,6\times6\,$ matrix $\,\mathcal C\,$ defined by
\begin{equation} 
  \mathcal C \boldsymbol{=} K \sigma_x \boldsymbol{\otimes} \mathbf I_3
\tag{B-01}\label{B-01} 
\end{equation}
is anti-unitary with property
\begin{equation} 
 \mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1} \boldsymbol{=}\mathcal C \quad \text{or} \quad \mathcal C^2   \boldsymbol{=}  \mathbf I_6
\tag{B-02}\label{B-02} 
\end{equation}
while the relation
\begin{equation} 
 \mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1} \mathbf M \mathcal C\boldsymbol{=-} \mathbf M
\tag{B-03}\label{B-03} 
\end{equation}
imposes to the $\,3\times3\,$ matrix $\,\mathbf B\,$ of equation \eqref{A-01b} the property
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf B\boldsymbol{=-}\mathbf B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}  
\tag{B-04}\label{B-04}
\end{equation} 
that is it equals to the negative of its transpose.
So we write formally
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf B\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \boldsymbol{-}\omega_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{=\omega\times}\,, \quad \boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\right) \in \mathbb{C}^3
\tag{B-05}\label{B-05}
\end{equation}
In case of a real 3-vector $\,\boldsymbol{\omega}\,$ the matrix $\,\mathbf B\,$ is anti-symmetric.

These properties of the matrices $\,\mathcal C,\mathbf B \,$ are proved in $\boldsymbol{\S}$**E**.

Note also that from equation \eqref{B-04}
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf B^{\boldsymbol{\dagger}}\boldsymbol{=-}\overline{\mathbf B}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 \hphantom{_3}& \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_3 & \boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} 0\hphantom{_3} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_2 &\boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\hphantom{_3}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{=-}\overline{\boldsymbol{\omega}}\boldsymbol{\times}
\tag{B-06}\label{B-06}
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{C. The Characteristic Equation of $\,\mathbf M\,$ and its solution}}$

The final expression of matrix $\,\mathbf M\,$ of equation \eqref{A-01a}  satisfying the condition \eqref{B-03} is
\begin{align}
\mathbf M & \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\epsilon_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\epsilon_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\epsilon_3 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_3 & \boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_2  & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} 0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{\omega}_2 &\boldsymbol{-}\overline{\omega}_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\epsilon_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf A \hphantom{^{\dagger}} &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} \mathbf B \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{C-01a}\label{C-01a}\\   
   &\text{where}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf A & \boldsymbol{=}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} \epsilon_1  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_2 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_3 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad 
  \mathbf B  \boldsymbol{=} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\omega_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \boldsymbol{-}\omega_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\omega_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
 \end{bmatrix}
\tag{C-01b}\label{C-01b}  
\end{align} 
So the matrix $\,\mathbf M\,$ is a function of two 3-vectors, the real $\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,$ and the complex in general $\,\boldsymbol{\omega}$
\begin{equation} 
  \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \epsilon_1   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_2   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_3   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3
 \quad \text{and} \quad 
\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \omega_1   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \omega_2   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \omega_3   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^3 
\tag{C-02}\label{C-02}
\end{equation}
The characteristic equation of $\,\mathbf M\,$ is of 6th order with respect to $\,\lambda\,$
\begin{equation} 
  a\lambda^6\boldsymbol{+}b\lambda^4\boldsymbol{+}c\lambda^2\boldsymbol{+}d\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{C-03}\label{C-03}
\end{equation}
or a cubic equation with respect to $\,\mathrm x\boldsymbol{=}\lambda^2\,$
\begin{equation} 
  a\mathrm x^3\boldsymbol{+}b\mathrm x^2\boldsymbol{+}c\mathrm x\boldsymbol{+}d\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{C-04}\label{C-04}
\end{equation}
The coefficients $\:a,b,c,d\:$ are **real** and their expressions as functions of the components of the vectors $\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,$ and $\,\boldsymbol{\omega}$ are given in $\boldsymbol{\S}$**D**.

Now, the analytic solution of the cubic equation \eqref{C-04} is well-known. First the change of variable
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm x\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm t\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}
\tag{C-05}\label{C-05}
\end{equation}
leads to a cubic that has no term in $\,\mathrm t^2$. After dividing by $\,a\,$ one gets the *depressed cubic equation*
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm t^3\boldsymbol{+}p\mathrm t\boldsymbol{+}q\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{C-06}\label{C-06}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
 \mathrm t & \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{b}{3a}
\tag{C-07a}\label{C-07a}\\   
 p & \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{3ac\boldsymbol{-}b^2}{3a^2}
\tag{C-07b}\label{C-07b}\\ 
 q & \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{2b^3\boldsymbol{-}9 a b c\boldsymbol{+}27a^2 d}{27a^3}
\tag{C-07c}\label{C-07c}
\end{align}
At this point we make use of the trigonometric solution for **three real roots** with respect to $\,\mathrm t$
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm t_n\boldsymbol{=}2\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{p}{3}}\cos\left[\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\dfrac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{3}{p}}\right)\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{2\pi\left(n-1\right)}{3}\right]\quad \left(n=1,2,3\right)
\tag{C-08}\label{C-08}
\end{equation}
This formula is due to **François Viète**.  It is purely real when the equation has three real roots (that is when $\,4p^3\boldsymbol{+}27q^2<0$).

From the roots \eqref{C-08} we have the roots of \eqref{C-04}  with respect to $\,\mathrm x$

<sup>\begin{equation} 
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!  \mathrm x_n\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}\boldsymbol{+}\mathrm t_n\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}\boldsymbol{+}2\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{p}{3}}\cos\left[\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\dfrac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{3}{p}}\right)\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{2\pi\left(n-1\right)}{3}\right]\quad \left(n=1,2,3\right)
\tag{C-09}\label{C-09}
\end{equation}</sup>

The roots $\:\mathrm x_n\left(n=1,2,3\right)\:$ are **non-negative real numbers** so the eigenvalues of $\,\mathbf M\,$ are

<sup>\begin{equation} 
  \boxed{\:\lambda_{1}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{4}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_1}\,,\quad \lambda_{2}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{5}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_2}\,,\quad \lambda_{3}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{6}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_3}\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\tag{C-10}\label{C-10}
\end{equation}</sup>

There is no need to prove that $\:\mathrm x_n\left(n=1,2,3\right)\:$ are non-negative real numbers since in any other case (such as one at least being negative real or complex) some of the eigenvalues $\:\lambda_k\left(k=1,2,\cdots,6 \right)\:$ would be complex in contradiction to the fact that an hermitian matrix as $\,\mathbf M\,$ has only real eigenvalues.

[image]

Viète's trigonometric expression of the roots of the cubic equation in the three-real-roots case lends itself to an elegant geometric interpretation in terms of a circle, see Figure-01. On the $\,\mathrm x\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm y\,$ graph of the function-characteristic polynomial with respect to $\,\mathrm x\boldsymbol{=}\lambda^2\,$
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm y\left(\mathrm x\right)\boldsymbol{=}a\mathrm x^3\boldsymbol{+}b\mathrm x^2\boldsymbol{+}c\mathrm x\boldsymbol{+}d
\tag{C-11}\label{C-11}
\end{equation}
we choose a point 
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm K\left(\mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a},\mathrm y_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{=}\text{ any}\right) 
\tag{C-12}\label{C-12} 
\end{equation} 
Note that this point has the same abscissa as the inflection point of the curve
\begin{equation} 
  \dfrac{\mathrm d^2 \mathrm y }{\mathrm d \mathrm x^2}\boldsymbol{=}0 \quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}\quad 6a\mathrm x\boldsymbol{+}2b\boldsymbol{=}0 \quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}\quad \boxed{\:\mathrm x_{\mathtt{inflection}}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}\:} 
\tag{C-13}\label{C-13} 
\end{equation} 
For our case this abscissa is positive since from equations \eqref{D-04a}, \eqref{D-04b}
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x_{\mathtt{inflection}}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\Vert\epsilon\Vert}^2\boldsymbol{+}2\boldsymbol{\Vert\omega\Vert}^2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)}{3}>0
\tag{C-14}\label{C-14}  
\end{equation}
With center the point $\:\mathrm K\:$ and radius 
\begin{equation} 
  R\boldsymbol{=}2\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{p}{3}}
\tag{C-15}\label{C-15}  
\end{equation}
we draw a circle and inscribe in it an equilateral triangle $\,\mathrm A_1\mathrm A_2\mathrm A_3\,$ inclined with respect to the$\,\mathrm x\boldsymbol{-}$axis by 
an angle
\begin{equation} 
  \theta\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\dfrac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{3}{p}}\right)
\tag{C-16}\label{C-16}  
\end{equation}
as shown in Figure-01. The abscissas of the vertices $\,\mathrm A_1,\mathrm A_2,\mathrm A_3\,$ are the three non-negative real roots $\,\mathrm x_1,\mathrm x_2,\mathrm x_3\,$ of equation \eqref{C-09}.

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{D. The coefficients of the Characteristic Equation of matrix $\,\mathbf M$}}$

<sup>The coefficients of the characteristic equations \eqref{C-03},\eqref{C-04} are
\begin{align}
 a & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{D-01a}\label{D-01a}\\   
 b & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\left[\left(\epsilon^2_1\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon^2_2\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon^2_2\right)\boldsymbol{+}2\left(\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\boldsymbol{+}\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\boldsymbol{+}\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)\right]
\tag{D-01b}\label{D-01b}\\
 c & \boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{2}\left[\left(\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)^2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]\boldsymbol{+}
\nonumber\\
& \hphantom{==}2\left[\left(\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)\left(\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)\boldsymbol{+}\left(\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)\left(\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)\boldsymbol{+}\left(\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)\left(\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]\boldsymbol{+}
\nonumber\\
& \hphantom{==}2\left(\epsilon^2_1\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\boldsymbol{+}   \epsilon^2_2\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon^2_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)\boldsymbol{+}2\left(\epsilon_2\epsilon_3\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\boldsymbol{+}   \epsilon_3\epsilon_1\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon_1\epsilon_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)\boldsymbol{+}
\nonumber\\
& \hphantom{==}\left[\left(\epsilon_2\epsilon_3\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_3\epsilon_1\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\right)^2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]
\tag{D-01c}\label{D-01c}\\
 d & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\left[\left(\epsilon_1\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_2\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)^2\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)^2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]
\nonumber\\
& \hphantom{-} \boldsymbol{-}2\left[\left(\epsilon_1\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)\left(\epsilon_2\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_2\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\right)\left(\epsilon_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)\boldsymbol{+}\left(\epsilon_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\right)\left(\epsilon_1\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\right)  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]\boldsymbol{+}
\nonumber\\
&  \hphantom{-} \boldsymbol{-}2\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3\left(\epsilon_1\omega_1\overline{\omega}_1\boldsymbol{+}   \epsilon_2\omega_2\overline{\omega}_2\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon_3\omega_3\overline{\omega}_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3\right)^2
\tag{D-01d}\label{D-01d} 
\end{align}</sup>

To simplify these expressions we define first the real 3-vector
\begin{equation} 
  \boldsymbol{\zeta}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \epsilon_2\epsilon_3  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_3\epsilon_1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_1\epsilon_2   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3
\tag{D-02}\label{D-02}
\end{equation}
and then the $\,3\times 3\,$ real matrix
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf Z\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} \zeta_1  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \zeta_2 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} \zeta_3 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} \epsilon_2\epsilon_3  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_3\epsilon_1 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} \epsilon_1\epsilon_2 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} 
\tag{D-03}\label{D-03}  
\end{equation}
The coefficients take the following simple expressions
\begin{align}
 a & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{D-04a}\label{D-04a}\\   
 b & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\Vert\epsilon\Vert}^2\boldsymbol{+}2\boldsymbol{\Vert\omega\Vert}^2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)
\tag{D-04b}\label{D-04b}\\
 c & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\Vert\omega\Vert}^4\boldsymbol{+}2\boldsymbol{\Vert \mathbf A\omega\Vert}^2\boldsymbol{+} 2\boldsymbol{\langle\mathbf Z\boldsymbol{\omega},\boldsymbol{\omega}\rangle}\boldsymbol{+}\boldsymbol{\Vert\zeta\Vert}^2
\tag{D-04c}\label{D-04c}\\    
 d & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\langle\mathbf A\boldsymbol{\omega},\boldsymbol{\omega}\rangle}\boldsymbol{+}\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right)^2
\tag{D-04d}\label{D-04d}
\end{align}

By $^{\prime\prime}\boldsymbol{\langle\hphantom{=},\hphantom{=}\rangle}^{\prime\prime}$ we mean the default inner product in the complex space $\,\mathbb C^3$.

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{E. Proving properties of  matrices $\,\mathcal C$ and $\,\mathbf B$}}$

For the $\,6\times6\,$ matrix $\,\mathcal C\,$ defined by equation \eqref{B-01} we have
\begin{equation} 
  \mathcal C \boldsymbol{=} K \sigma_x \boldsymbol{\otimes} \mathbf I_3\boldsymbol{=}K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 1  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 1  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\otimes}
  \mathbf I_3\boldsymbol{=}K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{E-01}\label{E-01} 
\end{equation}
Explicitly
\begin{equation} 
  \mathcal C \boldsymbol{=} K
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{E-02}\label{E-02}  
\end{equation}
From \eqref{E-01}

<sup>\begin{equation} 
  \mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}
  \left(K
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
  \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}K^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
  \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}K
\tag{E-03}\label{E-03} 
\end{equation}</sup>

because
\begin{equation} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
   \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}\quad \text{and} \quad K^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}K 
\tag{E-04}\label{E-04} 
\end{equation}
But these two operators commute
\begin{equation} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}K
  \boldsymbol{=}K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{E-05}\label{E-05} 
\end{equation} 
since the $\,6\times 6\,$ matrix is real.
So finally
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal C\boldsymbol{=}K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{E-06}\label{E-06} 
\end{equation} 
Although not necessary in the following we'll prove that the matrix $\,\mathcal C\,$ is anti-unitary. So, consider two complex 6-vectors $\,\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2 \in \mathbb{C}^6\,$ each one split to two complex 3-vectors 
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf x_1 \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\xi}_1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{\eta}_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}\,, \quad 
  \mathbf x_2 \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\xi}_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{\eta}_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
  \mathcal C\mathbf x_1 \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}\,, \quad 
  \mathcal C\mathbf x_2 \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_2  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{E-07}\label{E-07}  
\end{equation}
then
\begin{align} 
  \boldsymbol{\langle}\mathcal C \mathbf x_1,\mathcal C \mathbf x_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}_{\mathbb{C}^6} & \boldsymbol{=}  
  \Biggl\langle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
  \:\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_2  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}\Biggr\rangle_{\mathbb{C}^6}
 \tag{E-08}\label{E-08}\\
 &\boldsymbol{=} 
  \boldsymbol{\langle}\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_1,\overline{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}_{\mathbb{C}^3}\boldsymbol{+}\boldsymbol{\langle}\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_1,\overline{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}_{\mathbb{C}^3}\boldsymbol{=}\overline{\left(\boldsymbol{\langle}\boldsymbol{\eta}_1,\boldsymbol{\eta}_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}_{\mathbb{C}^3}\boldsymbol{+}\boldsymbol{\langle}\boldsymbol{\xi}_1,\boldsymbol{\xi}_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}_{\mathbb{C}^3} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \right)} 
\nonumber  
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation} 
  \boldsymbol{\langle}\mathcal C \mathbf x_1,\mathcal C \mathbf x_2\boldsymbol{\rangle} \boldsymbol{=}  
  \overline{\boldsymbol{\langle}\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}}
\tag{E-09}\label{E-09}  
\end{equation}

Now we'll prove \eqref{B-04} starting from \eqref{B-03} and the fact that $\,\mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal C$

<sup>\begin{align}
& \mathcal C^{\boldsymbol{-}1} \mathbf M \mathcal C \mathbf x\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}  \mathbf M\mathbf x \: \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}
 \tag{E-10}\label{E-10}\\
& K \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf A \hphantom{^{\dagger}} &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} \mathbf B \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
K \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} \mathbf I_3  & \hphantom{a} 0  \hphantom{a} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\xi}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{\eta} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}  
 \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf A \hphantom{^{\dagger}} &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} \mathbf B \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\xi}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{\eta} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \quad\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}
 \nonumber\\
 & K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} &   \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf A & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathbf B\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
K 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\eta}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{\xi} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
  \end{bmatrix}  
 \boldsymbol{=}\begin{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf A \boldsymbol{\xi}\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B\boldsymbol{\eta} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{\xi} \boldsymbol{+} \mathbf A\boldsymbol{\eta}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}\:\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}
 \nonumber\\
  & 
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \overline{\mathbf B^{\dagger}}\boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A \boldsymbol{\xi} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf A\boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{+}\overline{\mathbf B}\boldsymbol{\xi}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{=}\begin{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf A \boldsymbol{\xi}\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B\boldsymbol{\eta} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{\xi} \boldsymbol{+} \mathbf A\boldsymbol{\eta}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}\:\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}
    \left.
  \begin{cases}
   \overline{\mathbf B^{\dagger}}\boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B\boldsymbol{\eta} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \overline{\mathbf B}\boldsymbol{\xi}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf B^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{\xi}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{cases}\right\}
 \nonumber
\end{align}</sup>

so
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf B\boldsymbol{=-}\mathbf B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}  
\tag{E-11}\label{E-11} 
\end{equation}

Note : Because of insufficient space (maximum 30000 characters) I post a numerical example as another answer.

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$
Reference : [Cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation)

Comment: this is very detailed answer, I'm taking some time to go through this beautiful answer. First I need to take care of somethings.

Comment: @Galilean : Take your time. I want to believe that my answer is a right one. Is it possible to give your reference ??? It would be convenient to know the field of Physics it refers to.

Comment: This came up in Green's function analysis in many particle physics, 6 dimensions are for 6 flavours of particles. This matrix is effectively the hamiltonian of (quasi)particles after interaction is added on, with some systematic perturbation here and there. I've not come up with any references that deals with this kind of system. so the interest is completely personal.

Comment: @Galilean : OK. I hope I help a little.

Comment: I tried a few things, but, your answer is most compact and complete.

Answer (score 2):

Note : This answer is essentially an addendum to my first answer (due to limited space in answers)

$\boldsymbol{\S}\color{blue}{\textbf{F. Numerical Example}}$

Consider the following matrix

<sup>\begin{align}
\mathbf M & \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}1\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}2\boldsymbol{-}i3 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}1\boldsymbol{+}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}4\boldsymbol{+}i1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}2 & \boldsymbol{-}2\boldsymbol{+}i3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}4\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}1\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \boldsymbol{-}2\boldsymbol{-}i3  & \boldsymbol{-}1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \boldsymbol{-}1\boldsymbol{+}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} 0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}4\boldsymbol{+}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}2\boldsymbol{+}i3 &\boldsymbol{-}4\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}  
  \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{=}  
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf A \hphantom{^{\dagger}} &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} \mathbf B \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
   \mathbf B^{\dagger} & \boldsymbol{-} \mathbf A\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{F-01a}\label{F-01a}\\   
   &\text{where}
   \nonumber\\
   \mathbf A & \boldsymbol{=}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 1  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 3 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 2 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad 
  \mathbf B  \boldsymbol{=} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}1\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}2\boldsymbol{-}i3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}1\boldsymbol{+}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}4\boldsymbol{+}i1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
    \boldsymbol{-}2\boldsymbol{+}i3 &  \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}4\boldsymbol{-}i1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
 \end{bmatrix}
\tag{F-01b}\label{F-01b}  
\end{align}</sup>
 
The matrix $\,\mathbf M\,$ is produced by the following two 3-vectors, the real $\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,$ and the complex one $\,\boldsymbol{\omega}$
\begin{equation} 
  \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:1\:   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
  3   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  2   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3
 \quad \text{and} \quad  
\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:4\boldsymbol{-}i1\:   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  2\boldsymbol{-}i3   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  1\boldsymbol{+}i1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^3  
\tag{F-02}\label{F-02} 
\end{equation}
Above equations correspond to \eqref{C-01a},\eqref{C-01b} and \eqref{C-02} respectively.

To find the coefficients $\,a,b,c,d\,$ of the characteristic equation \eqref{C-03} or \eqref{C-04} we find first the terms appeared in their simple expressions \eqref{D-04a}-\eqref{D-04d}. So from \eqref{D-02},\eqref{D-03}
\begin{equation} 
  \boldsymbol{\zeta}\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \epsilon_2\epsilon_3  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_3\epsilon_1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \epsilon_1\epsilon_2   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  3\cdot 2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  2\cdot 1  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  1\cdot 3   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \:6 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  3 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{F-03}\label{F-03}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf Z\boldsymbol{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} \zeta_1  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} \zeta_2 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} \zeta_3 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \hphantom{a} 6  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 2 & \hphantom{a} 0 \hphantom{a}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
  \hphantom{a} 0  & \hphantom{a} 0 & \hphantom{a} 3 \hphantom{a}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
  \end{bmatrix} 
\tag{F-04}\label{F-04}  
\end{equation}
Also
\begin{align}
&\Vert\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\Vert^2  \boldsymbol{=} 14\,,\qquad  \Vert\boldsymbol{\omega}\Vert^2  \boldsymbol{=} 32\,,\qquad  \Vert\boldsymbol{\zeta}\Vert^2  \boldsymbol{=} 49\,,\qquad  \Vert\mathrm A\boldsymbol{\omega}\Vert^2  \boldsymbol{=} 142   
\tag{F-05a}\label{F-05a}\\
&\boldsymbol{\langle\mathbf A\boldsymbol{\omega},\boldsymbol{\omega}\rangle}\boldsymbol{=} 60\,,\qquad  \boldsymbol{\langle\mathbf Z\boldsymbol{\omega},\boldsymbol{\omega}\rangle}\boldsymbol{=} 134\,,\qquad  \epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3 \boldsymbol{=} 6 
\tag{F-05b}\label{F-05b} 
\end{align}
From expressions \eqref{D-04a}-\eqref{D-04d} we have
\begin{align}
 a & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{F-06a}\label{F-06a}\\   
 b & \boldsymbol{=}-78
\tag{F-06b}\label{F-06b}\\
 c & \boldsymbol{=}1625
\tag{F-06c}\label{F-06c}\\    
 d & \boldsymbol{=}-4356
\tag{F-06d}\label{F-06d}
\end{align}
The characteristic equation of $\,\mathbf M\,$ is of 6th order with respect to $\,\lambda\,$
\begin{equation} 
  \lambda^6\boldsymbol{-}78\lambda^4\boldsymbol{+}1625\lambda^2\boldsymbol{-}4356\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{F-07}\label{F-07}
\end{equation}
or a cubic equation with respect to $\,\mathrm x\boldsymbol{=}\lambda^2\,$
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm x^3\boldsymbol{-}78\mathrm x^2\boldsymbol{+}1625\mathrm x\boldsymbol{-}4356\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{F-08}\label{F-08} 
\end{equation}
This result is in full agreement with Mathematica output as shown in Figure-02.

[image]

From \eqref{C-07b},\eqref{C-07c} we have

\begin{equation}
 p  \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{3ac\boldsymbol{-}b^2}{3a^2}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{3\cdot 1\cdot 1625\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{-}78\right)^2}{3\cdot 1^2}\quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad
 \boxed{\:p \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}403\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:}
\tag{F-09a}\label{F-09a}
\end{equation}
 
<sup>\begin{equation}
 q  \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{2b^3\boldsymbol{-}9 a b c\boldsymbol{+}27a^2 d}{27a^3}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{2\left(\boldsymbol{-}78\right)^3\boldsymbol{-}9 \cdot 1\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{-}78\right)\cdot 1625\boldsymbol{+}27\cdot 1^2 \left(\boldsymbol{-}4356\right)}{27\cdot 1^3}
 \nonumber
\end{equation}</sup>
 
\begin{equation}
 \hphantom{\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{3ac\boldsymbol{-}b^2}{3a^2}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{3\cdot 1\cdot 1625\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{-}78\right)^2}{3\cdot 1^2}} \quad \:\:\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad \boxed{\:q\boldsymbol{=} 2742\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:}
\tag{F-09b}\label{F-09b}
\end{equation}

From \eqref{C-14},\eqref{C-15} and \eqref{C-15} we have respectively
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x_{\mathtt{inflection}}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{b}{3a}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\boldsymbol{-}78}{3\cdot 1}\quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad
 \boxed{\:\mathrm x_{_\mathrm K} \boldsymbol{=}26 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:}
\tag{F-10}\label{F-10}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
  R\boldsymbol{=}2\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{p}{3}}\boldsymbol{=}2\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\boldsymbol{-}403}{3}}\quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad
 \boxed{\:R \boldsymbol{=}23.1805 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:}
\tag{F-11}\label{F-11} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
  \theta\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\dfrac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{3}{p}}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left[\dfrac{3\cdot 2742}{2\cdot (\boldsymbol{-}403)}\sqrt{\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{3}{\boldsymbol{-}403}}\right] 
\nonumber 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad \theta\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\boldsymbol{-}0.8805657\right)\quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad
 \boxed{\:\theta\boldsymbol{=}0.882617 \text{  rad}\boldsymbol{=}50.57023^{\boldsymbol{\circ}}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:} 
\tag{F-12}\label{F-12}   
\end{equation}
From \eqref{C-14}
\begin{align} 
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathrm x_1\: &\:\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{+}R\cos\left(\theta\right)\boldsymbol{=}26\boldsymbol{+}23.1805\cos\left(0.882617\right)\boldsymbol{=}40.7226
\tag{F-13.1}\label{F-13.1}\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathrm x_2 \:&\:\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{+}R\cos\left(\theta\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)\boldsymbol{=}26\boldsymbol{+}23.1805\cos\left(\boldsymbol{-}1.211778\right)\boldsymbol{=}34.1446
\tag{F-13.2}\label{F-13.2}\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathrm x_3 \:&\:\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm x_{_\mathrm K}\boldsymbol{+}R\cos\left(\theta\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\right)\boldsymbol{=}26\boldsymbol{+}23.1805\cos\left(\boldsymbol{-}3.306173\right)\boldsymbol{=}3.1328
\tag{F-13.3}\label{F-13.3}
\end{align}
These three positive roots are shown on the $\mathrm x\boldsymbol{-}$axis in the graphical representation of the characteristic polynomial, see Figure-03.

Finally, the six real eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf M$ defined in equation  \eqref{F-01a} are
\begin{equation}
\left.
  \begin{cases}
    \lambda_{1}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{4}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_1}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{40.7226}\boldsymbol{=}6.3818\\
   \lambda_{2}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{5}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_2}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{34.1446}\boldsymbol{=}5.8433\\
   \lambda_{3}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\lambda_{6}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\mathrm x_3}\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\:\:3.1328}\boldsymbol{=}1.7700
  \end{cases}\right\}
 \tag{F-14}\label{F-14}  
\end{equation}

[image]